# Scrolling a 'Horizontally Scrollable div element' makes the parent scroll as well

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have implemented a TabbarController where in the user can swipe through different tabs. I have achieved this by adding 'touchstart', 'touchmove' & 'touchend' events. All the tabs have a horizontally scrollable element which when scrolled leads to invoking of 'touchmove' on parent which leads to parent and child scrolling at same time. Is it possible to restrict the scroll to child / restrict the touch event from being passed on from child to parent?

I have tried using 'overflow:hidden' on parent div and also tries using 'prevendefault()' on touch events.

Comment: Code. Fiddle. Please.

Comment: `event.stopPropagation()` - google and read about it - sounds like what you're after

Comment: @marekful The description does explain the desired and actual behaviour.

Comment: That may be true but we down't want to explain the solution. This site is about showing others how to change their existing code to eliminate problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally wrote a solution to cater to my problem. I iterate through the DOM objects to check for the scrollable area of the child elements when the Event callback propagates back to the Parent element where the listeners were added.
The Touch Event is not processed for parent if the current touched child has scrollable content.

```
var element:HTMLElement = event.target;
var cancel:boolean = false;

while (element && element.parentElement){
      if (element.scrollWidth > element.clientWidth){
          cancel = true;
          break;
      }
          element = element.parentElement;
}
```